# What are the possible causes of Lactase persistence?

Tags: physiology, enzymes, digestive-system, milk

Lactase enzyme which is responsible for the digestion lactose (a disaccharide milk sugar) normally its production decreases when a young mammal is weaned but mostly Humens continue to produce this enzyme throughout adulthood, this ability is termed as lactase persistence.
What is the reason and mechanism of this phenomenon?
what are the evolutionary basis of lactase persistence?

Comment: Welcome  Dr. Uzair Ali. We are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on and see our [homework-question policy](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Enjoy the Stackexchange network.

Comment: Interesting question. This paper, [Evolution of lactase persistence: an example of human niche construction](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rstb.2010.0268), published in a very reliable source, argues that lactase persistence is an example of niche construction: "Niche  construction  is the  process by  which organisms construct important components  of their local environment in ways that introduce novel selection pressures. Lactase persistence is one of the clearest examples of niche construction in humans".  The pdf seems to be freely available from the journal site